# Dbscan time duration gauge

Tags: programming

I'm running a Dbscan. On a matrix that's 10333 by 10333, using an epsilon value of 50. Is there any way to gauge how long this will take? It's been running for the past 8 hours now. Also does it depend on the magnitude of the elements value?